# Want to add string to HTML from AJAX request in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make a weather app with AJAX request and I am not really strong in angularJS. So I have something like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/6458vz1s/1/

and I can't add `locationHTML` to my HTML with `ng-bind-html` . It causes some errors like this:

[image]

[Screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTaM2.png)

When I add `ng-bind-html-unsafe` , there are no errors , but still no HTML

When I print it through `console.log` , it looks perfect. But just can't add it to HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `'ngSanitize'` to your module's dependencies

check documentation here : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml

```
WeatherApp=angular.module('WeatherApp',['ngSanitize']);
WeatherApp.controller('WeatherController', function($scope,$http){
$http.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/forecast/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json').success(function(response){
    $scope.Weather = response;
    $scope.locationHTML = "In the next two boxes You will see weather conditions in <b>" + $scope.Weather.location.city + "</b> city";
})
    .error(function(response){
        alert('Error occured with the weather app')
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh it worked, when I see my errors so simple, I feel a little desperate:) oh well... Thanks a lot !